# Overriding existing property of json, or adding next if not present in json

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have some JSON, declared as string for my testing purposes in main method.
My goal is to use JSONPATH with DocumentContext, to override property if property exists, and to add it if it does not exists.
Is there possibility to achieve that ?
My JSON

[How to add new node to Json using JsonPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971642/how-to-add-new-node-to-json-using-jsonpath)
[Convert a JSON object to another JSON object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425781/convert-a-json-object-to-another-json-object-in-java)
I've visited these two but my result is not JSON but "com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonReader@1ae369b7"

```
{
  "meta": {
    "drilldownEnabled": false
  },
  "chart": {
  renderTo:"container",
    "additionalData": {
      "dateTime": false,
      "datetype": "string",
      "cliccable": true,
      "drillable": false,
      "drillableChart": false,
      "isCockpit": true,
      "categoryColumn": "periodo_analisi",
      "categoryGroupBy": "",
      "categoryGroupByNamens": "",
      "categoryName": "periodo_analisi",
      "categoryOrderColumn": "",
      "categoryOrderType": "",
      "categoryStacked": "",
      "categoryStackedType": ""
    },
    "zoomType": "xy",
    "panning": true,
    "type": "column",
    "options3d": {
      "enabled": false,
      "alpha": 25,
      "beta": 15,
      "depth": 50,
      "viewDistance": 25
    },
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "heightDimType": "pixels",
    "widthDimType": "pixels",
    "plotBackgroundColor": null,
    "plotBorderWidth": null,
    "plotShadow": false,
    "borderColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "style": {
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "fontWeight": "",
      "fontSize": ""
    },
    "events": {}
  },
  "colors": [
    "#ff5722"
  ],
  "title": {
    "text": "",
    "style": {
      "align": "",
      "color": "",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "fontSize": "",
      "fontWeight": ""
    }
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "xAxis": [
    {
      "plotBands": [
        {
          "label": {
            "text": "",
            "align": "center"
          },
          "color": "",
          "from": 0,
          "to": 0
        }
      ],
      "plotLines": [
        {
          "label": {
            "text": "",
            "align": "center"
          },
          "color": "",
          "dashStyle": "",
          "value": 0,
          "width": 0
        }
      ],
      "type": "category",
      "id": 0,
      "title": {
        "customTitle": false,
        "text": "periodo_analisi",
        "style": {}
      },
      "labels": {
        "style": {
          "color": "",
          "fontFamily": "",
          "fontSize": "",
          "fontWeight": ""
        },
        "align": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "plotBands": [
        {
          "label": {
            "text": "",
            "align": "center"
          },
          "color": "",
          "from": 0,
          "to": 0
        }
      ],
      "plotLines": [
        {
          "label": {
            "text": "",
            "align": "center"
          },
          "color": "",
          "dashStyle": "",
          "value": 0,
          "width": 0,
          "zIndex": 1
        }
      ],
      "title": {
        "text": "NUM_GG_GIACENZA_AVG",
        "customTitle": false,
        "style": {
          "color": "",
          "fontFamily": "",
          "fontWeight": "",
          "fontSize": ""
        }
      },
      "labels": {
        "style": {
          "color": "",
          "fontFamily": "",
          "fontSize": "",
          "fontWeight": ""
        },
        "align": ""
      },
      "gridLineDashStyle": "$convertedTypeline",
      "minorGridLineDashStyle": "$convertedMinorTpeline"
    }
  ],
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "NUM_GG_GIACENZA_AVG",
      "dataLabels": {
        "style": {
          "color": "",
          "fontFamily": "",
          "fontWeight": "",
          "fontSize": "",
          "fontStyle": ""
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "labelFormat": "{y:,.2f}"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "drilldown": false,
          "y": 32.6667,
          "name": "Q1-2019",
          "datetype": "string"
        },
        {
          "drilldown": false,
          "y": 29,
          "name": "Q3-2018",
          "datetype": "string"
        },
        {
          "drilldown": false,
          "y": 134.5,
          "name": "Q4-2018",
          "datetype": "string",
          "color": "#F10AE8"
        }
      ],
      "selected": true,
      "tooltip": {
        "valueDecimals": 2,
        "scaleFactor": "empty",
        "ttBackColor": "#FCFFC5"
      },
      "yAxis": 0
    }
  ],
  "tooltip": {
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "borderRadius": 0,
    "followTouchMove": false,
    "followPointer": true,
    "useHTML": true,
    "backgroundColor": null,
    "style": {
      "padding": 0
    }
  },
  "lang": {
    "noData": ""
  },
  "noData": {
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "",
      "fontSize": "",
      "color": ""
    },
    "position": {
      "align": "center",
      "verticalAlign": "middle"
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "line": {
      "marker": {
        "symbol": "circle",
        "lineWidth": 2
      }
    },
    "column": {},
    "bar": {},
    "series": {
      "cursor": "pointer",
      "point": {
        "events": {}
      },
      "dataLabels": {
        "allowOverlap": true
      },
      "turboThreshold": 2000
    }
  }
}
```

I simply place this JSON in string as cc variable and write

```
DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(cc).set(JsonPath.compile("$.meta"), "nani");
        doc.json();

        System.out.println(doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the DocumentContext instance instead of its content.

Try:

```
System.out.println(doc.read([Your JsonPath]));
```

Go [here](https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/ReadContext.html) for more Info.